# How to Push object in an array of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I want to push objects inside inner array of array. How can I do it?

```
ticketsToAdd = [];
ticketsToAdd.push({
    "TicketId": "",
    "Attendees": []
})

for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    ticketsToAdd['Attendees'].push({
                        "EmailID": "",
                        "Phone": "",
                        "FirstName": "",
                        "LastName": "",
                        "Company": ""                          
    })
}
```

Comment: Change `ticketsToAdd['Attendees'].push(` to `ticketsToAdd[i]['Attendees'].push(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push only one time into `ticketsToAdd` array,

use,

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        ticketsToAdd[0]['Attendees'].push({
        "EmailID": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "Company": ""                          
        })  
    }
```

But, If you push multiple times, you have to use the index `i`

Since you are adding more objects into `ticketsToAdd` array, while inserting data into that array, use the number `i` from the iteration.

use `ticketsToAdd.length` to get the length first.

```
var ticketsToAdd = [];
ticketsToAdd.push({
    "TicketId": "",
    "Attendees": []
})

for(var i=0; i<ticketsToAdd.length; i++) {
  for(var y = 0; y<5; y++)
   {
      ticketsToAdd[i]['Attendees'].push({
        "EmailID": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "Company": ""
       })                          
   }   
}
```

**This gets all the objects from the array and pushes 5 times in each of it.**

Answer (score 5):

You need an index for access an array element.

```
ticketsToAdd[0]['Attendees'].push();
//          ^^^
```

```js
var ticketsToAdd = [],
    i;

ticketsToAdd.push({ TicketId: "", Attendees: [] });

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ticketsToAdd[0]['Attendees'].push({ EmailID: "", Phone: "", FirstName: "", LastName: "", Company: "" });
}

console.log(ticketsToAdd);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an array inside an array.

You have an array inside an object inside an array.

You need to first access the object before you can access the array inside it.

```
ticketsToAdd[0].Attendees.push(...)
```